# Do I stick with 12.04 lts or upgrade to 12.10 or higher?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, security

I recently bought a laptop with ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have only used windows so far, so I admit I'm a noob at ubuntu.

Since I only need it for reading, writing papers, entertainment and communication, do you suggest upgrading to 12.10 or higher? Upgrade manager only shows 12.10 for upgrading. Does that mean that I have to upgrade gradually to reach the latest versions?

I have to mention that security is a big deal to me as I have heard and read multiple times that ubuntu doesn't have significant virus threats present and that upgrading is the best way to protect my system (yeah yeah safe browsing too).

Answer (score 0):

The LTS in 12.04 LTS is supposed to mean Long Term Support, so it should get important updates like security updates for a "Long Term" (currently 5 years). You should be safe keeping 12.04 and just updating it, no need to upgrade to 12.10 or a newer version.

That said, the newer versions could offer newer features that 12.04 LTS may not have, like newer versions of programs (not just security & bigfix updates) or maybe even newer kernels with newer hardware support (someone correct me if I'm wrong there...)

But if everything works well on your 12.04 then keeping it is a fine idea.

---

FYI, for more available software options, you can enable main, universe, restricted, and multiverse (I think they're separated by license type) in the "Software Sources" or "Repositories" See this link for more info https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: So just keep updating.. Got it.
 Could you recommend me some programs from the software center, for example: defragmentator or other cleaning program (since I read that I don't need antivirus..), something fun or educational would be great!

Last but not least, are the Libre Office programs very different from the MS Office? Do they require a lot of time to get to know them?

Comment: If you're using an ext2/3/4 filesystem (linux "standard") they're not supposed to need defragmenting, and I haven't seen an easy way to do it even if you wanted to. The standard FS checking program is `fsck` (short for "filesystem check" apparently). `man fsck` reveals `fsck  is  simply  a  front-end for the various filesystem checkers (fsck.fstype) available under Linux`. There's different ones for fat (fsck.fat same as fsck.vfat, fsck.msdos), and other FS's minix, reiserfs, jfs, xfs... and for ntfs the `ntfs-3g` package has `ntfsck` or `ntfsfix` but ntfs still needs windows for big problems.

Comment: The Software center/manager should list some interesting sounding software, along with ratings which are good to see if at least a few people recommend something. Or Synaptic or `apt` in a terminal work too, but no reviews/ratings. Burning dvd's I like k3b (but it needs ~50megs of kde dependencies (worth it!). A graphical diff I like is `kdiff3-qt`. For games, I like the worms-like `hedgewars` but it's best with friends to blow up :) I haven't used MS office since version 97 or 2001 or so, LibreOffice just as good if not better IMO. Just browse around or search for anything interesting.

Comment: Ubuntu may still need to install special software to watch DVD's, some libcss-something... I haven't used plain Ubuntu for a few years, using Linux Mint XFCE (based on Ubuntu, generally the same but with extras like dvd/media support already installed, and a different desktop). I also use `archive.getdeb.net` for even more software, See http://www.playdeb.net/ and http://www.getdeb.net  They seem to have more games & apps, but may have less tested/more unstable versions, sticking with the "official" Ubuntu repositories might be safest. [And if my answer's helpful please select/check/upvote :]